# Android Retrofit - HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host {my base url}: No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit2, http-error

The project is using the latest retrofit version (2.3.0). If I turn off the internet connection on my phone or if no internet connection is available, retrofit is throwing a "HTTP FAILED" which is not caught by the onFailure() or onRespond(). This HTTP error is directed to the exception "Unable to resolve host (...)". I want to handle this error case in displaying a snackbar or something else. Currently I have no access to this exception and my loading screen will not stop due to not getting a respond message. Has anyone an idea how to solve that using retrofit?

The only working solution I found was to use interceptors checking every request if a internet connection is available. But there needs to be a better way to solve that issue, I hope.

Comment: Did you not see this - https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/644 ? In Retrofit 1.7, you can use `RetrofitError.getKind()` which will tell you if the error is a network, conversion, http, or unexpected error. In prior versions you could use `RetrofitError.isNetworkError()`.

Comment: Well I don't want to downgrade to version 1.7. Isn't there a solution which is working for 2.3 also?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the newer release has that as well. Check link

Comment: I'm pretty sure the newer release has that as well. Check link

Comment: Well it only states that you could use the callback method failure() which is not existing in 2.3.0. Instead the method onFailure is existing that is not being called when the HTTP FAILED is fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like my internal error handling was the problem. Retrofit is using the onFailure() to notify about HTTP FAILED (in version 2.3.0).